The legacy JS API is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0
I was using create-react-app before and now I switched the same project to vite and everything working fine except I am getting a warning log as follows

Deprecation [legacy-js-api]: The legacy JS API is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

I want to get rid of these warnings from log while development and build the application. Following are my dependencies
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.1.5",
    "@tanstack/react-table": "^8.17.3",
    "i18next": "^23.12.1",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^8.0.0",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-i18next": "^14.1.3",
    "react-indiana-drag-scroll": "^2.2.0",
    "react-toastify": "^10.0.5",
    "recharts": "^2.13.0-alpha.4",
    "recoil": "^0.7.7",
    "sass": "^1.79.1",
    "uuid": "^10.0.0"
  }
}

Node version is v22.7.0

https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#js-api

The default API when using Vite is currently set to legacy, but you can change it in your vite.config.[js/ts].
export default defineConfig({
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        api: 'modern-compiler' // or "modern"
      }
    }
  }
})

Reference: https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options#css-preprocessoroptions

I use SASS in Nuxt, so I copied your solution to my nuxt.config.ts, and replaced "scss" with "sass". Thanks!

@AlphaHuang can u share the piece of code here which you have added in nuxt.config.ts ? TIA

So, big question: how do we know when we can remove this workaround and Vite's default is set to use the modern compiler?

@Hashan94 I added an answer to this thread.

@VictorZamanian It's not that much of a workaround, and not something you need to remove. However, it's going to be changed in Vite 6.

Didn't work for me, still receiving the same warnings. :(

on scss node,you need add a new child : silenceDeprecations: ["legacy-js-api"],

Added following lines in the vite config fixes the issue, I missed it  on the sass documentation (changelog). This will hide the warning message from console. Thanks @Family for pointing this out.
Please find sass changelog
//vite.config.ts
export default defineConfig({
  //..other config
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        silenceDeprecations: ["legacy-js-api"],
      },
    },
  },
})


But how to properly fix it and not just silence the warning?

please refer the accepted answer of this question, instead of silenceDeprecations, you can use api: 'modern-compiler'

I tried it, but still getting the warning. I'm using svelte-kit, which uses vite.

Try using key as ‘sass’  instead of ‘scss’ inside preprocessorOptions object if you are using svelte-kit.

@Hashan94 I didn't figure out how to post with format in a reply, so I'm adding an answer here.
My nuxt.config.ts is like this,
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  vite: {
    css: {
      preprocessorOptions: {
        sass: {
          api: 'modern',
        },
      },
    },
  }
});


Working, but: Just make sure to update your project to match scss or sass instead.

Thanks @AdrianoCahete you saved my day! This should be part of the answer.

It looks like a different Sass compiler is being used, namely dart-sass.
node-sass will no longer be developed and will be replaced by dart-sass.
Somewhere in your code or modules sass.render() is still used, which will no longer be supported as of Dart-Sass 2.0.
You or the developer of the affected module has to replace it with sass.compile() or sass.compileString().
More information about the JS-API can be found here:
https://sass-lang.com/documentation/js-api/

create a file vite.config.ts
vite.config.ts:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
    css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
        scss: {
        api: 'modern-compiler' // or "modern"
        }
    }
    } })


I received the warning when I used the Quasar Vite plugin.
In my vite.config.js, I added:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
      css: {
        preprocessorOptions: {
          scss: {
            api: 'modern-compiler', // or "modern", "legacy"
            // silenceDeprecations: ["legacy-js-api"]
          },
        },
      }
    })

Then, in main.js, I replaced:
import 'quasar/src/css/index.sass'

with the precompiled css version:
import 'quasar/dist/quasar.css'

This resolved the warning.
