Deprecation Warning: The legacy JS API is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0. at run vitest
vitest.config.js:
import { defineConfig, mergeConfig } from 'vitest/config'

import viteConfig from './vite.config'

export default mergeConfig(
    viteConfig,
    defineConfig({
        test: {
            globals: true,
            environment: 'jsdom',
            setupFiles: './vitest.setup.ts',
            css: {
                preprocessorOptions: {
                    scss: {
                        api: 'modern-compiler',
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }),
)

vite.config.ts
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import * as path from 'node:path'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import dynamicImport from 'vite-plugin-dynamic-import'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react(), dynamicImport()],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            app: path.resolve(__dirname, './src', 'app'),
            pages: path.resolve(__dirname, './src', 'pages'),
            widgets: path.resolve(__dirname, './src', 'widgets'),
            features: path.resolve(__dirname, './src', 'features'),
            entities: path.resolve(__dirname, './src', 'entities'),
            shared: path.resolve(__dirname, './src', 'shared'),
        },
    },
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            output: {
                entryFileNames: `assets/[name].[hash].js`,
                chunkFileNames: `assets/[name].[hash].js`,
                assetFileNames: `assets/[name].[hash].[ext]`,
            },
        },
    },
    css: {
        preprocessorOptions: {
            scss: {
                api: 'modern-compiler', // or "modern"
            },
        },
    },
})


Tests is completed, but many warnings in console. I dont can founded resolve this. Please help me

I've tried it in different ways change config, write gpt, read docs vite and vitest, nothing not help. Please help me
Error exactly when run tests, at run dev error nothing

The Warning is telling you that the API that you are using is legacy and you need to either ignore the warning and pin to this version of the library or you need to upgrade to the new API. If go to the link provided in the error it tells you how to migrate to the new API.

Have you read the docs in the More Info section of the warning?

What is this "modern-compiler" option and why do you use it?

this option work in vite.config.ts, but not working in vitest.config.ts. I don't know how to force he work

preprocessorOptions - used in vitest.config.ts because I've tried it - it option work only vite.config.ts

This question is similar to: The legacy JS API is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It is already answered here, both are same issues : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78997907/the-legacy-js-api-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-dart-sass-2-0-0

Finded resolve. deleted vite vitest sass, again install. And vite config updated:
export default defineConfig({
    css: {
        preprocessorOptions: {
            scss: {
                api: 'modern',
            },
        },
    },
    test: {
        globals: true,
        environment: 'jsdom',
        setupFiles: './vitest.setup.ts',
    },
})

vitest config deleted
